# Google Colab Runtime Dies every time the code is run

Tags: keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, transfer-learning

Came through an issue when trying to train my deep learning model using keras. There were no issues till yesterday. Now whenever the code is run and before it reaches to train model line of code (model.fit()), always the message "Runtime Dies" is shown.

i. Previously I tried with 4 GB of dataset, it was working perfect

ii. Tried with 8 GB of dataset and runtime kept on restaring.

iii. Tried with 4 GB and 5 GB dataset and the error 'runtime dies' keep on prompting.

The code is related to standard Transfer Learning approach, trying with InceptionNet and InceptionResNet. I'm not sharing the code here as the code is to be submitted in one of the deep learning challenges.

When tried to run the following code, it's shown that only 564 MB of GPU-RAM is free to process further.

## How much GPU is allocated

!ln -sf /opt/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi

!pip install gputil

!pip install psutil

!pip install humanize

import psutil

import humanize

import os

import GPUtil as GPU

GPUs = GPU.getGPUs()

gpu = GPUs[0]

def printm():

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

print("Gen RAM Free: " + humanize.naturalsize( psutil.virtual_memory().available ), " I Proc size: " + humanize.naturalsize( process.memory_info().rss))

print("GPU RAM Free: {0:.0f}MB | Used: {1:.0f}MB | Util {2:3.0f}% | Total {3:.0f}MB".format(gpu.memoryFree, gpu.memoryUsed, gpu.memoryUtil*100, gpu.memoryTotal))

printm()

[GPU-RAM Resource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Olc.png)

Can this be the reason behind the issue?